# What is the smallest unit of work that is sensible to parallelize with actors?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

While Scala actors are described as light-weight, Akka actors even more so, there is obviously some overhead to using them.

So my question is, what is the smallest unit of work that is worth parallelising with Actors (assuming it can be parallelized)? Is it only worth it if there is some potentially latency or there are a *lot* of heavy calculations?

I'm looking for a general rule of thumb that I can easily apply in my everyday work.

EDIT: The answers so far have made me realise that what I'm interested in is perhaps actually the *inverse* of the question that I originally asked. So:

Assuming that structuring my program with actors is a very good fit, and therefore incurs no extra development overhead (or even incurs *less* development overhead than a non-actor implementation would), but the units of work it performs are quite small - is there a point at which using actors would be damaging in terms of performance and should be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether to use actors is not primarily a question of the unit of work, its main benefit is to make concurrent programs easier to get right. In exchange for this, you need to model your solution according to a different paradigm.

So, you need to decide first whether to use concurrency at all (which may be due to performance or correctness) and then whether to use actors. The latter is very much a matter of taste, although with Akka 2.0 I would need good reasons not to, since you get distributability (up & out) essentially for free with very little overhead.

If you still want to decide the other way around, a rule of thumb from our performance tests might be that the target message processing rate should not be higher than a few million per second.

Comment: Interesting point, and has made me think that maybe I asked the question the wrong way round: actors have greatly simplified the design of what I want to do, they are a very good fit in terms of the structure of the program, however the units of work are small enough that I worry using actors may have a negative effect on performance.

Comment: Negative effects should only play a role if you require very high message rates (as I said: more than just a few million per second) OR if you are dominated by latency. With actors you have an easier time doing things in parallel, which means more things per second, but each single thing will take a bit longer. The classical trade-off.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers - one of those unfortunate situations where you just have to choose one to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

My rule of thumb--for everyday work--is that if it takes milliseconds then it's potentially worth parallelizing.  Although the transaction rates are higher than that (usually no more than a few 10s of microseconds of overhead), I like to stay well away from overhead-dominated cases.  Of course, it may need to take much longer than a few milliseconds to *actually* be worth parallelizing.  You always have to balance time time taken by writing more code against the time saved running it.

Comment: Sounds sensible - what would be your opinion on a program that was a very good structural fit for actors, but whose units of work took less than milliseconds?

Comment: @Russell - If performance is acceptable, use actors.  If it is not, benchmark to see if actors are taking a majority of the time (you could get an idea if you e.g. send double messages).

Comment: Thanks both for your answers - one of those unfortunate situations where you just have to choose one to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If no side effects are expected in work units then it is better to make decision for work splitting in run-time:

```
protected T compute() {
  if (r – l <= T1 || getSurplusQueuedTaskCount() >= T2)
    return problem.solve(l, r);
// decompose
}
```

Where:

T1 = N / (L * Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors())

N - Size of work in units

L = 8..16 - Load factor, configured manually

T2 = 1..3 - Max length of work queue after all stealings

Here is presentation with much more details and figures:

http://shipilev.net/pub/talks/jeeconf-May2012-forkjoin.pdf

Comment: Note that that presentation is not in English; here is a working link: http://shipilev.net/pub/talks/jeeconf-May2012-forkjoin.pdf